# Python OpenSSL generating public and private key pair

Tags: python, openssl, private, public

I am having problem finding a command that would generate a public and private key pair using OpenSSL. Could someone show me some example code of this in action.

Thank you

Comment: You mean a server certificate and key? Can you use the `openssl` command line tool? What's the code you're having problems with?

Comment: I am using openssl commandline yes, and this is for certificates. I have tried using http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Transwiki:Generate_a_keypair_using_OpenSSL but I think need to have this in a Pkey format http://pyopenssl.sourceforge.net/pyOpenSSL.html/openssl-pkey.html

Comment: pyOpenSSL has nothing to do with the command-line tool.

Comment: I only started to use command line to generate keys after I couldnt do it in PyOpenSSL

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using the [pyOpenSSL](https://github.com/pyca/pyopenssl) bindings:

> ```
> OpenSSL.crypto.PKey().generate_key(type, bits)
> ```
>
> Generate a public/private key pair of the type `type` (one of `TYPE_RSA` and `TYPE_DSA`) with the size `bits`.

[Docs](https://pyopenssl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/crypto.html#pkey-objects)

Comment: How do I use this to generate a pair of keys, doesn't it generate one at a time?

Comment: @user: Quote from answer which in turn quotes the docs: "Generate a public/private key pair"

Comment: publicKey = Pkey()        publicKey.generate_key(TYPE_RSA,128)      privateKey = Pkey()        privateKey.generate_key(TYPE_RSA,128) ? Or does it produce a tuplet. Could you provide sample code please

Comment: You only need to do it once; the `PKey` object contains all the data you need. Later, you will probably use the key pair to sign a certificate.

Comment: what does a PKey look like and how would I use it with a certificate

Comment: [Here's](https://skippylovesmalorie.wordpress.com/2010/02/12/how-to-generate-a-self-signed-certificate-using-pyopenssl/) some code I found on Google.

Answer (score 0):

```
def makeCertificate(**kw):
    keypair = PKey()
    keypair.generate_key(TYPE_RSA, 1024)

    certificate = X509()
    certificate.gmtime_adj_notBefore(0)
    certificate.gmtime_adj_notAfter(60 * 60 * 24 * 365) # One year
    for xname in certificate.get_issuer(), certificate.get_subject():
        for (k, v) in kw.items():
            setattr(xname, k, nativeString(v))

    certificate.set_serial_number(counter())
    certificate.set_pubkey(keypair)
    certificate.sign(keypair, "md5")

    return keypair, certificate
```